# Optimising Python implementation using Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have a Python implementation which computes the SHA3 code (with customised rate and capacity values) for a file. The Python implementation works absolutely fine and gives the correct output but is very slow performance wise.

After reading some articles and surfing the internet, I figured out that Cython is a good way to improve the performance of the python code.

I tried modifying my code for cython but I am unsure about whether what I have implemented is correct or not. Here is my implementation:

```
import binascii
import time
from cpython import array

cdef class Keccak:
   
    cdef int __STATE_LENGTH = 1600
    cdef int __DELIMITED_SUFFIX = 0x06
    cdef int __SHA3_RATE_LENGTH = 256
    cdef int __state_bytes_length, __capacity_bytes_length, __rate_bytes_length, __hash_bytes_length
    cdef array.array __state_in_bytes, __hash_bytes
    
    def __init__(self,cdef int variant=2):
        self.__state_bytes_length = self.__STATE_LENGTH // 8
        self.__delimited_suffix = self.__DELIMITED_SUFFIX

        self.__SHA3_RATE_LENGTH = variant
        self.__rate_bytes_length = self.__SHA3_RATE_LENGTH // 8
        self.__state_in_bytes = bytearray([0 for i in range(self.__state_bytes_length)])
        self.__capacity_bytes_length = self.__state_bytes_length - self.__rate_bytes_length
        self.__hash_bytes_length = self.__capacity_bytes_length//2
        self.__hash_bytes = bytearray()
#         return 0; 
    
    @staticmethod
    def __rotate_word(cdef array.array word, cdef int n):
        return ((word >> (64 - (n % 64))) + (word << (n % 64))) % (1 << 64)

    @staticmethod
    def __load_64_bytes(cdef array.array byte_array):
        return sum((byte_array[i] << (8 * i)) for i in range(8))

    @staticmethod
    def __store_64_bytes(cdef int integer):
        return list((integer >> (8 * i)) % 256 for i in range(8))

    def __run_inner_hash_functions(self, cdef array.array lanes):
        cdef int R = 1
        cdef int x,y,i,j
        cdef array.array C,D,current, T
        for round in range(24):

            # θ
            C = [lanes[x][0] ^ lanes[x][1] ^ lanes[x][2] ^ lanes[x][3] ^ lanes[x][4] for x in range(5)]
            D = [C[(x + 4) % 5] ^ self.__rotate_word(C[(x + 1) % 5], 1) for x in range(5)]
            lanes = [[lanes[x][y] ^ D[x] for y in range(5)] for x in range(5)]

            # ρ and π
            (x, y) = (1, 0)
            current = lanes[x][y]
            for t in range(24):
                (x, y) = (y, (2 * x + 3 * y) % 5)
                (current, lanes[x][y]) = (lanes[x][y], self.__rotate_word(current, (t + 1) * (t + 2) // 2))

            # χ
            for y in range(5):
                T = [lanes[x][y] for x in range(5)]
                for x in range(5):
                    lanes[x][y] = T[x] ^ ((~T[(x + 1) % 5]) & T[(x + 2) % 5])

            # ι
            for j in range(7):
                R = ((R << 1) ^ ((R >> 7) * 0x71)) % 256
                if R & 2:
                    lanes[0][0] = lanes[0][0] ^ (1 << ((1 << j) - 1))

        return lanes

    def __run_hash_function(self):
        # In column first order
        cdef int x,y,i,j
        cdef array.array state_in_bytes, lanes
        lanes = [[self.__load_64_bytes(self.__state_in_bytes[8 * (x + 5 * y):
                                                             8 * (x + 5 * y) + 8])
                  for y in range(5)]
                 for x in range(5)]

        lanes = self.__run_inner_hash_functions(lanes)

        state_in_bytes = bytearray(200)
        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                state_in_bytes[8 * (x + 5 * y):
                               8 * (x + 5 * y) + 8] = self.__store_64_bytes(lanes[x][y])

        self.__state_in_bytes = state_in_bytes

    def get_hash_of(self, cdef array.array input_bytes):
        cdef int block_size, message_offset = 0,0
        
        # === Absorb all the input blocks ===
        while message_offset < len(input_bytes):
            block_size = min(len(input_bytes) - message_offset, self.__rate_bytes_length)

            for i in range(block_size):
                self.__state_in_bytes[i] ^= input_bytes[message_offset + i]

            message_offset += block_size

            if block_size == self.__rate_bytes_length:
                self.__run_hash_function()
                block_size = 0

        # === Do the padding and switch to the squeezing phase ===
        self.__state_in_bytes[block_size] ^= self.__delimited_suffix

        if ((self.__delimited_suffix & 0x80) != 0) and (block_size == (self.__rate_bytes_length - 1)):
            self.__run_hash_function()

        self.__state_in_bytes[self.__rate_bytes_length - 1] ^= 0x80
        self.__run_hash_function()

        # === Squeeze out all the output blocks ===
        while self.__hash_bytes_length > 0:
            block_size = min(self.__hash_bytes_length, self.__rate_bytes_length)
            self.__hash_bytes += self.__state_in_bytes[0: block_size]
            self.__hash_bytes_length -= block_size

            if self.__hash_bytes_length > 0:
                self.__run_hash_function()

        return binascii.hexlify(self.__hash_bytes)



variant = int(input("Enter the rate value of SHA3: \n"))
keccak = None
try:
    keccak = Keccak(variant)
except ValueError as v:
    print(v)
    exit(0)

file_name = input("Enter a file name: ")
file = open(file_name, "rb")
contents = file.read()
# for i in range(10):
temp = contents.decode()
start = time.time()
original_hash = keccak.get_hash_of(temp)
end = time.time()
execution_time = end-start
execution_times.append(execution_time)
print("Hash:" + str(original_hash)[2:-1] + "\nLength of Hash: " + str(len(original_hash)))
print("Time taken for hashing: " + str(float(execution_time)) + " Seconds")
file.close()
# print("Average Execution Time (10 iterations): ", sum(execution_times)/len(execution_times))
```

### Update

I tried to run the Python file using the following methods:'

- `python3 filename.py` and `python3 filename.pyx`
  The errors I get is:

```
File "filename.py(x)", line 5
    cdef class Keccak:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

- When I compile using `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`
  The error that I get is as follows:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import binascii
^
------------------------------------------------------------

filename.pyx:1:0: 'filename' is not a valid module name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("SHA_3_1600_variableInput_Final-Cython.pyx")
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1103, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1226, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: filename.pyx
```

The setup.py file is in place and has the following:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("filename.pyx")
)
```

Comment: Why are you unsure whether it is correct? Are you not able to test it?

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed with testing it. It gives me syntax errors. @kaya3

Comment: If it gives you syntax errors then you know it is *not* correct. What specific error does it give you? Please see [mcve].

Comment: You don't actually get the error "'filename' is not a valid module name", because that would be a valid module name. If I look really hard I can see your module name is "SHA_3_1600_variableInput_Final-Cython". The character `-` cannot be a module name. You are not making it easy for anyone to answer you by not showing what you are actually doing.

Comment: @DavidW I copied the exact error that I received. The filename is actually SHA_3_1600_variableInput_Final-Cython.py and the same name with .pyx as well. I am unable to figure out how to proceed with testing my code after making the required updates according to cython. The pure Python implementation of my code works absolutely fine.

Comment: You __did not__ copy the exact error! Your setup.py file says "filename.pyx". Your error message says a mixture of "filename.pyx" and "SHA_3_1600_variableInput_Final-Cython.pyx". This is impossible. Like I said before, your immediate problem is with the `-` character (which cannot be part of a Python module name). If your pure Python version works fine and you cannot get Cython to work then I suggest you don't use Cython.

Answer (score 1):

Some very quick hints:

```
cdef class Keccak:
   
    cdef int __STATE_LENGTH = 1600
```

This doesn't work. In Python something similar to this would set a class variable called `__STATE_LENGTH` to 1600. You could then override it with an instance variable of the same names.

For a `cdef class`:

- If you want a class variable they can't be typed, thus:

  ```
  cdef class Keccak:

      __STATE_LENGTH = 1600
  ```

  would work.
- If you want an instance variable then you can't set a default value. You must set it in the constructor.

  ```
  cdef class Keccak:
      cdef int __STATE_LENGTH
      def __init__(self, ...):
          self.__STATE_LENGTH = 1600
  ```

---

```
def __init__(self,cdef int variant=2):
```

Don't use `cdef` for function arguments. Instead use

```
def __init__(self, int variant=2):
```

---

Finally you need to pick a module name without the `-` character in it. This is a basic Python module naming rule and nothing to do with Cython. This is something that we only find out buried deep in an edit to the question - the code claim to run is clearly not the code you actually run since you say setup.py contains

```
cythonize("filename.pyx")
```

the error message shows `"filename"`, but the traceback shows that you run

```
cythonize("SHA_3_1600_variableInput_Final-Cython.pyx")
```

Trying to debug a non-reproducible example is wasting everybody's time.